# Android early boot console over usb

Tags: android, linux-kernel, porting

I'm trying to port newer kernel versions onto my Nexus S device.

Most newer kernels panic very early on in the boot process. I would like to debug this. However, since the phone has been provided to me by my school, I cannot get a hold of a serial port (if it does exist..not sure)

I'm not sure what keywords to search for..I have found this recurring phrase `UEFI` which I don't understand.

Is there any way I can obtain the messages via USB onto my PC?

Comment: Have you tried using 'adb shell'?

Comment: adb is available only after the kernel begins init and starts the Android's init.rc..in my experience, the kernel crashes much much earlier

Comment: You are right.  We used to use JTAG to debug those boot-up issues, but that will be unavailable in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to setup a serial console to capture the boot-loader and Linux-kernel console messages over the USB port of a Nexus S. Essentially one needs to setup a USB-to-UART converter modified to fit the micro-USB port of the Nexus S.

Detailed instructions with screenshots are available in this [**article**](http://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/SamsungSerial).